# git-tfs pushing yout .git folder

Tags: git-tfs

I'm new to git-tfs and was wonder if there was a way to ensure that 'some' version of the .git folder would be sent to TFS for storage? (Unless I'm missing something)

If our setup is local dev -> tfs server; then the only copy of the .git would be on the workstation of the developer.  Or does this even matter?

A senerio needs to be covered, where we could port all TFS central sources to GIT(hub/lab). Having the .git folder included would allow for this.

Comment: Can you be clearer and better describe your goal? Here is a good doc how to migrate from TFVC : https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/usecases/migrate_tfs_to_git.md

Comment: What's the mean of  `'some' version of the .get folder would be sent to TFS for storage?` Did you want to keep different version of the .get folder  or just like the normal files in source control keep one version, keep covered with changeset.

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT It was my lack of understanding with how TFS  stores the Git. Just cloning from a local workstation would be fine. Scripts can be created for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git in TFS does not use TFS source control. Its a separate GIT system.  You shouldn't need to check-in your .git folder.

When you want to move your code to Git(hub/lab) you can do that by cloning the source to your local machine and then pushing it up to the remote Git server.